# Setting element to position absolute causes it to ignore min and max width in CSS

Tags: css

It is as if the width properties are not even there. I have tried just using min or max but that did not work either.

```
ul {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 20px;
    position: absolute; top: 95px; left: 0;
    min-width: 230px; max-width: 460px;
}
```

Comment: Specify something for the height like `auto`?

Comment: I want the <ul> to be at least 230px wide, but no more than 460px wide. It is not expanding in width though.

Comment: Everything works as expected... http://jsfiddle.net/L2x58/1/ Tested in FF3.6, Safari, Chrome. Maybe you are looking your code in an Browser which not supports these css propertys. What browser are you using?

Comment: As you can see in my example it works.

Comment: What is the factor you are expecting to push the width up? What is the content of the list like?

Comment: Your right that your example works using my code; just cannot figure out why it's not working for me. Will keep looking for that "small error."

Comment: The content is very basic. Right now it's: <li>I am some content that should help expand the width of the ul but for some reason the ul ignores the min and max width so instead I just fall down and use the min-width as if it was the only width declaration.</li>

Comment: Im pretty sure the error is somewhere above in your css code. Maybe you've defined an other selector with a higher specifity as your plain ul. Please provide more code and an example html if possible.

Comment: Yep its a dumb bug that has been removed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I had a similar problem with `max-height`. `Overflow: hidden` worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Position: absolute will make the element choose the min-width only.

Solution: You can try to;
1. Set the current "ul" element's position:relative, the the parent element of this "ul" to to relative as well. Then use the "Top:##px, Left:##px or etc" to change it's size.

Comment: Thanks! This was a great help!